# I cant iterate through pixels of all the image, it is iterating through parts of it. OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following code:

```
void white(Mat&src,Mat&dst){

    double h = src.cols;
    double w = src.rows;

    dst = src.clone();

    for (int i = 0; i < dst.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dst.cols; j++) {
            dst.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

My expected result is to get a completely white image, however, I get this result:

**Input Image:**

[image]

**Output Image:**

[image]

Comment: Dst.at<uchar>(j,i) = 255

Comment: It's a color image but you set only one value for  each pixel. That can't be correct.

Comment: @Zeta I got an "External component has thrown an error" when flipping the i and j.

Comment: @ThomasSablik What can I possibly do?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.. I thought you did x,y.. not y,x

Comment: `dst.at<uchar>(i, j) = 255;` should be something like `for (std::size_t c = 0; c < 3; ++c) dst.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[c] = 255;` or `for (std::size_t c = 0; c < 3; ++c) dst.at<uchar>(i, j, c) = 255;`

Comment: @Zeta solution not working? If not your image not gray but rgb? Then try Thomas solution

Comment: @ThomasSablik It is also throwing an error, I wrote this instead:
 dst.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = 255;
 dst.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 255;
 dst.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 255; and it worked, thank you.

Comment: You want `dst` to be a new `Mat` of the same size and type as `src`, and with all the values set to `(255,255,255)`. That's a [single constructor call](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a286371a6196eaaaf0b86e158590460b7), no loops or other shenanigans involved. Read (thoroughly) the documentation of the fundamental OpenCV data types, to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a color image. Each pixel consists of 3 values. You have to set each color channel

```
void white(Mat&src,Mat&dst){
  double h = src.cols;
  double w = src.rows;
  dst = src.clone();
  for (int i = 0; i < dst.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dst.cols; j++) {
      for (std::size_t c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {
        dst.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[c] = 255;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a rather complicated way of writing `dst = cv::Mat(src.size(), src.type(), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));`...